# By what criteria is the line aligned in edge slide even mode?

Tags: modeling

[image]

It is loop cut. I know that even mode works based on the left or right edge.[image]

But if I edge slide the Horizontal line in the middle, it comes out weird like a screenshot in even mode. It doesn't correspond with either the top, bottom, left or right.

Comment: Hi :). You're sliding a single vertex, not the whole edge ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your drawing, you are only sliding a vertex.  To edge slide you have to select the entire edge.

That said, to answer your question:

If you look in the upper left corner of the 3D viewport during an edge slide you will see something like this:

[image: Edge slide tool help]

The *Even* setting is the first part of the criteria.

If *Even* is `OFF` as in my screen shot, then to quote the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/edge_slide.html)

> the position of vertices on the edge loop move as a percentage of the distance between their original position and the adjacent edge loop, regardless of the edges’ lengths.

that is the movement depends on the shape of the object.

But if *Even* is `ON` another option, *Flipped* appears and that option controls the critera:

[image: Edge Slide showing flipped option]

Again quoting the manual:

> When Even mode is active, this flips between the two adjacent edge loops the active edge loop will match.

`ON` or `OFF` are weird choices for the option names, but basically they indicate which side the sliding edge will try to mimic.  If you have set *Even* `ON` a yellow line will appear showing which direction the edge is trying to mimic.

Finally, the shortcuts for changing *Even* or *Flipped* are the letters shown in parenthesis just before the options.  You press <kbd>E</kbd> to toggle *Even* between `ON` and `OFF` and when *Even* is `ON` you toggle *Flipped* by pressing <kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: Now that I've done the loop cut up and down, I understand why you're saying you've only chosen a single edge. Thank you.